# Cascading Parent- Child

Tags: css

I want to have all  .box p color pink but seems That all the .box p who are inside #container have red color. I hoped that cascade will change the color but I think I made a mistake.

Can you show me where I'm wrong please.

thanks

/***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Buvbvn</title>
<style type="text/css">
p {color: #F00;}



/* container holds all visible page elements */
#container{
padding:20px;
border:20px solid #000;
background: #CCC;
}


.box{
margin: 10px;
padding:20px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}



/* Make text red only for paragraphs within the container */
#container  p {
  color: #F00;
  }


/* Make text pink only for paragraphs within the box class */
 .box p {
  color: #FF00FF;
  }

</style>



</head>
<body>

<div id ="container">
<p>This is our content area.</p>
<div class = "box">
<p >I'm in a box!</p>



</div>
<div class = "box">
<p >I'm also in a box!</p>
</div>

</div>

<div class = "box">
<p >I'm also in a box!</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Do you want all element with a class box to have pink text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the cascade, it's the specificity of the selectors. A selector based on an `id` is more specific than one based on a `class`.

Your current code produces this: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vBRKk/).

To amend that so that all paragraphs inside a `.box` are pink you can either remove the `id` from the selector, to have only `p`, or add the class to the selector, to give: `#content .box p`:

```
#container .box p, /* addresses those paragraphs inside a .box that's inside #container */
.box p { /* addresses those paragraphs inside a .box, but not necessarily the #container */
color: #FF00FF;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vBRKk/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
.box p {
  color: #FF00FF !important;
}
```

Comment: While this works, it's important to remember that `!important` is taking a sledgehammer to crack a walnut. Amending the selectors is usually easier, in the long run... (this does **not** represent a down-vote, just a (hopefully) constructive criticism).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend:

```
p {
    color: #F00; /* Red */
}

.box p {
    color: #F0F; /* Pink */
}
```